# about royalty of Tezos NFT

Tags: smart-contracts

I want to know about the royalties of Tezos NFT. how can I collect the royalty. what are the restriction on the Tezos side. how to write the smart contract with including royalty and are there any standards about the royalty.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard for token royalties.
In general, they are managed offchain since they are defined in [token metadata](https://tzip.tezosagora.org/proposal/tzip-12/#token-metadata) which aren't readable onchain when stored on ipfs

Exemple: https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmfGMCF4B7ZhZmJdKs14Z6Wrg9pV2Mtyz1TtTVWXhGm9mA

Comment: thanks for your answer @Thomas
can I know about the Decimals and the nat value of the shares in royalties.